# How to develop dialog gauge in tcl / tk that gets loop value and updates in scale widget by moving it

Tags: linux, loops, tcl, tk-toolkit, progress

I'm trying to make a progress bar dialog like GNU/Linux **Xdialog --gauge**

Apparently you should get a value, which is updated for 'one second', from time to time.

This increment is done through a `for` loop already pre-configured to give the progressive count.

From my tests I did, and how far my knowledge of **tcl/tk** could go is like this:

```
proc bar { pos } {
global txt
set txt $pos
}

set btn [button .btn -text "Play" -relief groove -command { bar $pos }]

scale .scl -length 200 -width 5 -orient horizontal -from 0 -to 100 -resolution 1 -variable value -sliderlength 5 -sliderrelief flat -activebackground blue -command { bar } -showvalue 0

label .lbl -textvariable txt -width 5

grid $btn -row 0 -column 0
grid .scl -row 0 -column 1
grid .lbl -row 0 -column 2

global value
for {set value 0} {$value < 10} {incr value} {  
after 1000; # delay
if {$value < 10} { puts "Number: $value" }
bind . "$btn invoke"
}
```

This works, so in the console .. it does not show the form, window with the scale widget being slowly moved. So I need help from the most experienced how can I get this?

I created a multi-frame animation to get a better idea. Look:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
after 1000; # delay
```

just blocks and does not allow Tcl/Tk to do any processing.
Since your program has not yet entered the event loop, nothing will be displayed.

In some cases, whatever code that ends up replacing the 'after' command will have
delays that will allow screen updates.

```
# don't put the bind inside the for loop
# is this even needed?
bind . "$btn invoke"

set ::waitvar 0
for {set value 0} {$value < 10} {incr value} {  
   # a simplistic solution for purposes of this example
   # vwait cannot be nested, and should be used very carefully or not at all.
   after 1000 set ::waitvar 1
   vwait ::waitvar
   set ::waitvar 0
}
```

A better method will be something more like:

```
  proc updateScale { v } {
     global value
     set value $v
  }

  proc checkProgress { } {
     # query the progress of the task and see how far along it is
     set progress [queryProgress]
     updateScale $progress
     after 1000 [list checkProgress]
  }

  # schedule a call to checkProgress to start things off.
  after 1000 [list checkProgress]
  # and now the program enters the event loop
```

Comment: I was wondering if it's hard to create a progress bar for videos. Because that's what I'm trying to do with Mplayer, already embed it in the window now I'm creating the controls with focus and need to measure the current and running time, multiply and divide by 100 to update. Am I correct about this? Do you have any suggestions? Or should I open another thread for that too?

Comment: Use the 'checkProgress' method I suggested.  The problem will be how to get the progress from mplayer.  I haven't played around with mplayer in a long time, and I don't recall whether I implemented that portion or not.   I think I used a telnet interface to interface to mplayer.  Interfacing to mplayer is definitely material for another question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you've got a synchronous delay loop. You need an asynchronous one so that display updates can be processed.

```
coroutine countUp apply {{} {  # <<< launch coroutine for asynchronous state
    global value
    for {set value 0} {$value < 10} {incr value} {
        after 1000 [info coroutine]; yield; # <<< suspend coro for 1 second
        puts "Number: $value"
    }
}}
```

(It is possible to write this code without a coroutine, but the code is less clear.)

And you are recommended to use a `ttk::progressbar` when you want a progress bar. Correct user visual cues for what it is, etc.

Comment: (It is possible to write this code without a coroutine, but the code is less clear.) This method you said you can do was what I wanted to know.

Comment: Where you mentioned: _And it is recommended to use a `ttk::progressbar` when you want a progress bar._ But my knowledge is still limited to `pack`, `place` and `grid` geometry. But I will make an effort to study this other type of geometry: `ttk::`.

Comment: I went searching for this `coroutine` syntax that I had never seen in handouts and websites that I had access to on tcl / tk. She's new to me, and I found a lot of information on this site - https://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.6/tcl/TclCmd/coroutine.html. I noticed that it was introduced in the Tk8.6.x version and I am making use of the previous version which is Tk8.5.x. So I get the error while executing the script: **Error in startup script: invalid command name "coroutine".**